# Hibernate query using if statement

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I am trying to write a hibernate query and I am using a StringBuilder and set 3 separate set of strings for ce, pe, and both. How can I add it to my hibernate query? I want to add it where i added a comment to "add flag here". My Flag type are enums "Y" or "N".

```
        StringBuffer queryByCos4Allocation = new StringBuffer();
    Flag ceIngress = null;
    Flag ceEgress = null;
    Flag peIngress = null;
    Flag peEgress = null;
    String      ce = null;
    String      pe = null;
    String both = null;

    if (Flag.Y.equals(ceIngress) || Flag.Y.equals(ceEgress)){
        ce =      " AND (CE_INGRESS_FLAG = 'Y' OR CE_EGRESS_FLAG = 'Y')  "
                + " AND (PE_INGRESS_FLAG = 'N' OR PE_EGRESS_FLAG = 'N') " ;
    }if (Flag.Y.equals(peIngress) || Flag.Y.equals(peEgress)){
        pe =      " AND (CE_INGRESS_FLAG = 'N' OR CE_EGRESS_FLAG = 'N')  "
                + " AND (PE_INGRESS_FLAG = 'Y' OR PE_EGRESS_FLAG = 'Y') " ;
    }if (ce == pe){
        both =    " AND (CE_INGRESS_FLAG = 'Y' OR CE_EGRESS_FLAG = 'Y')  "
                + " AND (PE_INGRESS_FLAG = 'Y' OR PE_EGRESS_FLAG = 'Y') " ;
    }

    queryByCos4Allocation.append("  SELECT * FROM TRAFFIC_PROFILE " ).append( 
                "   WHERE COS_MODEL = 'cos4'  " ).append(
                "   AND DIRECTION = ?  " ).append(
                        /* 
                         * add my Flag case here 
                         * */
                "   and  TRAFFIC_PROFILE_ID IN " ).append(
                "   ( " ).append(
                "   select distinct (C1.Traffic_PROFILE_ID) from Cos_Class_Allocation C1, " ).append(
                "   Cos_Class_Allocation C2, Cos_Class_Allocation C3, Cos_Class_Allocation C4  " ).append(
                "   where c1.class_name = 'COS1' AND c1.CLASS_ALLOCATION = ? " ).append(
                "   and c2.class_name = 'COS2' AND c2.CLASS_ALLOCATION = ? " ).append(
                "   and c3.class_name = 'COS3' AND c3.CLASS_ALLOCATION = ? " ).append(
                "   and c4.class_name = 'COS4' AND c4.CLASS_ALLOCATION = ? " ).append(
                "   and C1.TRAFFIC_PROFILE_ID = c2.TRAFFIC_PROFILE_ID " ).append(
                "   and C1.TRAFFIC_PROFILE_ID = c3.TRAFFIC_PROFILE_ID " ).append(
                "   and C1.TRAFFIC_PROFILE_ID = c4.TRAFFIC_PROFILE_ID); " );
```

Comment: be carefull, ce==pe is not right, they are Strings and must be compared with .equals

Comment: do you want to append ce, pe or both to your code?

Comment: Make a own method for ifs and return String there. Otheroption is use of Criteria more dynamic.

Comment: @melli-182 yes append depending on the if statement condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use another variable to store what part of the code you want to append:

```
StringBuffer queryByCos4Allocation = new StringBuffer();
Flag ceIngress = null;
Flag ceEgress = null;
Flag peIngress = null;
Flag peEgress = null;
String      ce = null;
String      pe = null;
String both = null;
String toAppend = "";

if (Flag.Y.equals(ceIngress) || Flag.Y.equals(ceEgress)){
    ce =      " AND (CE_INGRESS_FLAG = 'Y' OR CE_EGRESS_FLAG = 'Y')  "
            + " AND (PE_INGRESS_FLAG = 'N' OR PE_EGRESS_FLAG = 'N') ";
    toAppend=ce;
}if (Flag.Y.equals(peIngress) || Flag.Y.equals(peEgress)){
    pe =      " AND (CE_INGRESS_FLAG = 'N' OR CE_EGRESS_FLAG = 'N')  "
            + " AND (PE_INGRESS_FLAG = 'Y' OR PE_EGRESS_FLAG = 'Y') " ;         toAppend=pe;
}if (ce!=null && ce.equals(pe)){
    both =    " AND (CE_INGRESS_FLAG = 'Y' OR CE_EGRESS_FLAG = 'Y')  "
            + " AND (PE_INGRESS_FLAG = 'Y' OR PE_EGRESS_FLAG = 'Y') " ;         toAppend=both;
}
queryByCos4Allocation.append("  SELECT * FROM TRAFFIC_PROFILE " ).append( 
            "   WHERE COS_MODEL = 'cos4'  " ).append(
            "   AND DIRECTION = ?  " ).append(
                    toAppend +
            "   and  TRAFFIC_PROFILE_ID IN " ).append(
            "   ( " ).append(
            "   select distinct (C1.Traffic_PROFILE_ID) from Cos_Class_Allocation C1, " ).append(
            "   Cos_Class_Allocation C2, Cos_Class_Allocation C3, Cos_Class_Allocation C4  " ).append(
            "   where c1.class_name = 'COS1' AND c1.CLASS_ALLOCATION = ? " ).append(
            "   and c2.class_name = 'COS2' AND c2.CLASS_ALLOCATION = ? " ).append(
            "   and c3.class_name = 'COS3' AND c3.CLASS_ALLOCATION = ? " ).append(
            "   and c4.class_name = 'COS4' AND c4.CLASS_ALLOCATION = ? " ).append(
            "   and C1.TRAFFIC_PROFILE_ID = c2.TRAFFIC_PROFILE_ID " ).append(
            "   and C1.TRAFFIC_PROFILE_ID = c3.TRAFFIC_PROFILE_ID " ).append(
            "   and C1.TRAFFIC_PROFILE_ID = c4.TRAFFIC_PROFILE_ID); " );
```